# rotating text at bottom right of a div

Tags: css

I have some text in a div which is also in divs for having a double borders around it.

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/43y46/

I would like to place a text rotated 90° at bottom right of it.

Something like this:

[image]

My rotated text should be placed in the blue space on the screenshot.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can apply a position:absolute; and a bottom:0;

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/) Use this style for your text span.

```
.rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know but I was not able to do it myself, I suck with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Done! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/43y46/1/

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I was looking for :) You rotated the wrong text. What I want is rotating a new text (ex: Copyright) and place this text at bottom right (in place of blue on the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/43y46/5/

Comment: updated my answer - it works now - except the text is aligned to top - i can't get it working with bottom alignment...

Comment: What you do is not bad, nearly ok but it doesn't rotate in IE9.

Comment: i omitted the rules for ie, added them on http://jsfiddle.net/43y46/6/ - can't check in ie9 - however - IE8 shows only first 4 characters ("rota") - no idea why

Comment: it appears IE sets the 1.5em width to both width & height on rotated element. so bottom line: it's a very tricky one, don't think it's doable.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
<div id="content">                
    <div class="outer-gray"> 
        <div class="inner-gray">                 
            @RenderBody()
            <div class="rotate">Text rotated here</div>
        </div>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.rotate
{    
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 5px;    
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #cccccc;
    padding-top: 70px;

    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```